# Why do my data miner threads collect some IDs many times, others not at all?

Tags: python, multithreading, data-mining

I'm writing a data miner in python with urllib2 and BeautifulSoup to parse some websites, and in attempting to divide its processes across a few threads, I get the following output:

> Successfully scraped ID 301
>
> Successfully scraped ID 301
>
> Empty result at ID 301

"Successful" means I got the data I needed. "Empty" means the page doesn't have what I need. "ID" is an integer affixed to the URL, like site.com/blog/post/.

First off, each thread should be parsing different URLs, not the same URLs many times. Second, I shouldn't be getting different results for the same URL.

I'm threading the processes in the following way: I instantiate some threads, pass each of them shares of a list of URLs to parse, and send them on their merry way. Here's the code:

```
def constructURLs(settings,idList):
    assert type(settings) is dict
    url = settings['url']
    return [url.replace('<id>',str(ID)) for ID in idList]        

def miner(urls,results):
    for url in urls:
        data = spider.parse(url)
        appendData(data,results)

def mine(settings,results):
    (...)
    urls = constructURLs(settings,idList)
    threads = 3 # number of threads
    urlList = [urls[i::threads] for i in xrange(threads)]
    for urls in urlList:
        t = threading.Thread(target=miner,args=(urls,results))
        t.start()
```

So why are my threads parsing the same results many times, when they should all have unique lists? Why do they return different results, even on the same ID? If you'd like to see more of the code, just ask and I will happily provide. Thank you for whatever insight you can provide!

Comment: Is your function appendData() thread-safe?  If it is getting called re-entrantly from multiple threads, any shared variables it uses might be getting overwritten.

Comment: That would explain many of the IDs that appear missing from the results file, but the print statements about scraping success are made before writing to results.

Comment: Actually, that issue of thread-safe might be the culprit. The error is happening inside of parse(), I know that much. The function uses a module-local variable that all instances of the function modify. That's probably where the error is happening. Thanks for your insight!